# Typo in Edit questions and answers

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits

In [Edit questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit) you can find this text at the bottom:

> Users with this privilege level get access to the Low Quality Posts
>   list where they can **improved** the low quality posts, or suggest they
>   are deleted.

I think it should be corrected to:

> Users with this privilege level get access to the Low Quality Posts
>   list where they can **improve** the low quality posts, or suggest they
>   are deleted.

Comment: And there is a typo in your question. :)

Comment: Haha sure! Corrected : )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for letting us know.

Typo fixed and should be visible on the next build.

Comment: Thank you for your work!

Comment: AFAIK Privileges pages on MSO are wikis that pushed to the entire network. But when does it get pushed? [animuson has already updated on MSO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/66737/13) on Feb 11 but it is not updated in SO.

Comment: @hims056 - It will get pushed out shortly.